# SSRS: How to display a hyperlink in sql services reporting

Tags: html, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS for 2008 R2 to display some data-generated reports. In my database table, I have a cell called Remarks. It usually contains links to software defects. The cell is nvarchar(max) and I've added links such as http://stackoverflow.com.
However, when the report is displayed, the link is not clickable as expected.
What do I need to do make the link clickable?
Many thanks for any help.
J.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe you can put the anchor tags in the text and SSRS will render them as links.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Two approaches, the first assumes data is pre-formatted as a URL (e.g. `https://www.google.com`). The second assumes the URL is contained within some other text (e.g. 'This is a link to [Google](https://www.google.com)').

---

### URL Only

1. Right-click the field in design view, select `Text Box Properties`.
   [image: Report Builder Field Right-Click]
2. Select the `Action` pane, select the `Go to URL` radio button.
3. In the `Select URL` textbox, enter the field value expression.
   [image: Field Action URL]

---

### URL Embedded in Text

1. Double-click the field in design view, then right-click `Create Placeholder`.
   [image: Report Builder Placeholder]
2. In the `Value` textbox, enter the field value expression containing HTML tags.
3. Under `Markup Type`, check the `HTML - Interpret tags as styles` radio button.
   [image: Report Builder Placeholder options]
4. Verify link is displayed when report is run.
   [image: Report Builder Placeholder Output]

---

Comment: I believe what he's saying is he has a Remarks field that, among other remarks, might contain a URL, but it isn't just the URL. If that's the case, I don't believe this solution will work.

Comment: Updated with placeholder solution to account for URLs embedded in text. Assumption is that URL is wrapped with `<a></a>` tags in data.

Comment: Beargle, thanks for such a clear answer and with screenshots! The second option was the one I was after and it works a treat.

Comment: I am creating a hyperlink in a text box by using the placeholder properties.  What information should I put for "Value" on the General tab?  I assume that I should put the url I want to link to with the Action property.

Answer (score 4):

**How to create a text box in the title area that is a hyperlink (opens in another window)**

1] Drag Text box to title area from Toolbar to the design surface

2] Then from the 'Report Data' pane on the left side, drag any field from the dataset into the text box
     {this is to create a 'placeholder' rather than a plain 'textbox'

3] Right click on the field, in the textbox, go to 'Placeholder Properties'

4] in the action Pane, of the 'Placeholder Properties' window, click 'Go to URL', 
    then click the fx, i.e. expression button, and paste the following into the expression:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://172.15.189.14:64444/ElectronicForms.aspx','_blank'))"
```

click [ok] to close the expression window

5] Go to the 'General' tab, in the 'Placeholder Properties' widow. 
    The Value field will be populated with the name of the field that you dragged into the text box, in step2, 
    delete the name of the field. Then click the fx, expression button, and type the following into the expression window:

="Click for Help"

Then click [ok] to close the expression window

Then click [ok] to close the 'PlaceHolder Properties' window

Comment: It took me a bit to digest and understand what you are attempting to do here.  It seems you are leveraging the fact that the report will be output to HTML and as such you can embed javascript.  Is this the case?  If so, then what happens when you render this report in something other than a web browser - such as when using the Report Services Control component used in windows forms development?  Will this solution work, or is this SSRS web based solution only?