# SSRS action on field in CSV list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

My client requires a report that produces a comma separated list of files in one column of a grid.  I know I can use a FOR XML Path in my query to yield these results. However, the client wants to be able to click on an individual value in that CSV and be taken to a link for that element in the list. For example, the column in the report would look like:

1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg

He needs the ability to click on the 2.jpg, and go to that actual file. I know I can put in an action for the entire field to go to one URL, but can I narrow that action down to a specific part of the CSV list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [placeholders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207048.aspx) to embed hyperlinks in comma delimited text, you'll need to wrap each value with an anchor tag and href. See the **URL Embedded in Text** section of my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878752/ssrs-how-to-display-a-hyperlink-in-sql-services-reporting/14879036#14879036) an example.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7330e/5) of sample code for adding markup. It's ugly in SQL but works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to use the example in SQL Fiddle to get a return that has the HTML markup. I also added the placeholder, as per the second example. However, i get a string returned that has the markup, but is not clickable. Am I missing a step?

Comment: @user1873604 What about step 3, setting HTML tags to be interpreted as styles? If you did that, please update your post with the HTML and a screenshot of the placeholder properties window for the report field.

Comment: Thanks, I did do that step. Unfortunately, this is on a restricted network, so I am unable to send a screen shot. My computer that faces the internet is not allowed to have development tools, so I cannot recreate it there, either

Comment: The HTML look like it is properly formatted. When I copy out an HTML string from the report (between commas) and paste it into excel, it gives me a valid link. It's just not recognizing the HTML in SSRS for some reason.

Comment: This works, but had to do some modifications to make it work with multiple URLs

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workable solution. The problem seems to lie in the fact that there are multiple URLs in the list. If i only return a single URL, it works fine. so, instead of a CS list, I return one at a time and use a matrix to group the other fields.