# How to change url and avoid refreshing the whole page when an hyperlink is clicked from the SSRS Report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, ssrs-2012

My question is, is there a way to change the url without refreshing the whole web page when an hyperlink from the SSRS Report is clicked?

I tried 2 different implementations of hyperlink in SSRS Report RDLC which are indicated here: 
[SSRS: How to display a hyperlink in sql services reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878752/ssrs-how-to-display-a-hyperlink-in-sql-services-reporting)

**1st Way**
    Textbox Properties > Action pane > Go to URL radio button > Selected URL: **http:// localhost:(port)/#/Path/ViewDetails**

**2nd Way**
    Create Placeholder > Right click > Placeholder Properties > General Pane > On Markup type: HTML - Interpret HTML tags at styles > Value: **="< a href="http:// localhost:(port)/#/Path/ViewDetails">View Details< /a>"**

I have an MVC project that uses AngularJS and has implemented local processing mode of SSRS Report Viewer. The Report Viewer was implemented in an ASPX page (MVC.ViewPage)

**ReportViewer.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SampleProject.Models.ReportInfo>" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server"
            SizeToReportContent="true" AsyncRendering="false" Visible="true"
            ProcessingMode="Local" EnableViewState="true"
            InternalBorderStyle="None" BorderStyle="None" InternalBorderWidth="0"
            KeepSessionAlive="false" >
      </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
    <script runat="server">
       override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e){
          // some report viewer initialization here
          // some datasource data population code here
       }
    </script>
```

I put load this ASPX page into an IFrame of an MVC Partial View.

**ViewDetail.cshtml**

```
<div>
  <iframe src="{{report.viewDetailPath}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

**viewDetail.js (AngularJS Controller)**

```
angular.module('project').controller("ViewDetailCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.report = {
                     id: // some guid,
                     viewDetailPath: '/Reports/ReportViewer';
                  }
}
```

I have a RDLC report with an hyperlink "View Detail".

I want my app to behave like a Single Page Application. When I click the "View Detail" link from the report, instead of refreshing the whole page, it will only change the URL and execute a javascript method from the AngularJS controller.

I have also implemented a $routeProvider of AngularJS in order to look like a single page application.

**app.js**

```
project.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
     when('/', {template: 'NYI'}).
     when('/Path/ViewDetails', {controller: 'ViewDetailCtrl', templateUrl: '/Reports/ViewDetail'}).
     otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

**ReportsController.cs(MVC Controller)**

```
public PartialViewResult ViewDetail(){
  return PartialView("~/Views/Reports/ViewDetail.cshtml");
}

public ActionResult ReportViewer(){
  return View("~/Views/Reports/ReportViewer.aspx", new ReportInfo());
}
```

The $routeProvider to make the application like a single page app, does not work when the SSRS Report hyperlink changed the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to attach a "onclick" event handler to the links in question. This onclick handler can then prevent the click but instead change the URL by e.g. using angular's $location.update function (or setting $window.location.href in newer versions).

Here is angular's documentation on how to manipulate the URL: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

And here is a very simple example of such an event handler and how to attach it to a link. You might have to use something like getElementsByClassname instead (with a loop) or even some complicated selector:

```
function linkclick(e) {
    alert(e.target);
    e.preventDefault();
}
document.getElementById('testid').onclick = linkclick;
```

See it working here. It will just alert the URL clicked, but prevent the browser from opening that URL: http://jsfiddle.net/eJBfn/

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I supposed the <a href...</a> in your example is the Hyperlink in my SSRS Report. then I placed the javascript function in my ReportViewer.aspx. I got an exception. The javascript was loaded first and it could not find the element id 'testid' since the SSRS Report is not yet loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about deep linking in angular you need to use #/ before all of your anchor tag hrefs:

```
<a href="#/yourpath"></a>
```

Comment: I have tried that but still, the whole page refreshes. I have a guess that SSRS Report is causing the whole page refresh thing. I just dont know how to avoid SSRS from doing that.